# Pathauto URL allowing unauthorised user to view

Tags: users, uri, path-aliases

I have a content type that only authorised users are able to view i.e. mysite.net/node/66 (Access denied message for non authorised users) but when I view the same content using an alias of node/66 i.e. url mysite.net/content/for-registered-users-to-view (node/66) I'm able to view this content whether I'm logged in or not.

I would like to have the same (Access denied message for non authorised users) when viewing this alias. Can anyone tell me why this is happening I've checked my permission but I just can't work it out. I'm using [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) (version 7.x-1.3) to automatically create the aliases

Comment: How are you doing access control?